# Specified key was too long while migrating

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :user

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :content


      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I created these two entities in a new project and when I run migrate I get this error:

```
rails db:setup
Created database 'rails_api_development'
Created database 'rails_api_test'
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/projects/rails-api/db/schema.rb doesn't exist yet. Run `rails db:migrate` to create it, then try again. If you do not intend to use a database, you should instead alter C:/Users/admin/Desktop/projects/rails-api/config/application.rb to limit the frameworks that will be loaded.

admin@Desktop MINGW32 ~/Desktop/projects/rails-api (master)
$ rails db:migrate
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Caused by:
Mysql2::Error: Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Also, why does it say mysql2 even though I entered mysql as the database? What the heck is wrong with rails? Is it a problem with the ORM or some other config issues?

Comment: 'mysql2' is the name of the gem, that's allright. Do you have other migrations apart from those two? run the command with `--trace` argument to see more information on the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SET GLOBAL default_storage_engine = 'InnoDB';

Running this in phpmyadmin solved it. Seems to be an issue with MySQL database.